# Spring MongoDb template connection with authentication

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am using spring template to create a connection with Mongodb. Below is the part of code which makes connection with Mongodb and it is working fine.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new      MongoClient(Utils.getPropertyValue(Constants.DB_HOST_URL,      Constants.DB_CONFIG_FILE), options);
simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient,     Utils.getPropertyValue(Constants.DB_NAME,  Constants.DB_CONFIG_FILE));
```

But I want to add the username and password at the time of DB connection. I have tried with below code but it gives database connection error.

```
SimpleMongoDbFactory(com.mongodb.Mongo mongo, String databaseName, UserCredentials credentials)
```

code we are using :

```
MongoDbFactory getMongoDbFactory() throws DBException {
    mLogger.info("Mongo DB Configuration....");
    String username = "xxxxx";
    String password = "xxxxxxx";
    String authenticationDatabaseName = "xxxxxxx";
    UserCredentials credentials = new UserCredentials(username,password);       
    try {
        if(null==simpleMongoDbFactory){
            WriteConcern writeConcern = new WriteConcern(1, 0, true);

            MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();              
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Utils.getPropertyValue(Constants.DB_HOST_URL, Constants.DB_CONFIG_FILE), options);
            simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, Utils.getPropertyValue(Constants.DB_NAME,  Constants.DB_CONFIG_FILE),credentials);
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        throw new DBException("Exception occurred while connection to mongo. Error is ::"+ exception.getMessage(), exception);
    } catch (UnknownHostException exception) {
        throw new DBException("Exception occurred while connection to mongo. Error is ::"+ exception.getMessage(), exception);
    }
```

and it gives error :

```
SEVERE: Exception occurred while getting job details. Error is ::not authorized for query on socialcare.automatedjobdetails
```

com.mongodb.MongoException: not authorized for query on socialcare.automatedjobdetails
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.throwOnQueryFailure(QueryResultIterator.java:214)
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.init(QueryResultIterator.java:198)
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.initFromQueryResponse(QueryResultIterator.java:176)
at com.mongodb.QueryResultIterator.(QueryResultIterator.java:64)

Comment: Can you add the error to the post and actual code that is causing the exception ?

Comment: Hi Veeram, I have edited the code and error  in my above post

Comment: Looks like user doesn't have the necessary role. Check the roles for the user. You need `read/ readWrite ` role for the database you are querying.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Usage of 'UserCredentials' with 'MongoClient' is no longer supported. Please use 'MongoCredential' for 'MongoClient' or just 'Mongo'.

Comment: Are you asking something ? I'm not sure what you mean by the exception.

Comment: I am getting below error error that -- Usage of 'UserCredentials' with 'MongoClient' is no longer supported. Please use 'MongoCredential' for 'MongoClient' or just 'Mongo

Comment: I have got the solution and now it is working in my machine.  Please find below the code     MongoClient mongoClient = null; 
MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential("<userName>", 
   "<database>","<password>".toCharArray()); 

mLogger.info("MongoClient....");

try { 
mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress( 
  <HOST>, <PORT_NAME>), 
 Arrays.asList(mongoCredential)); 
} catch (UnknownHostException e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}